# NoSQL: insert an array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a question in the homework assignment.

Suppose that each actor can work in multiple movies. We want to record the names of movies for each actor as an embedded array within a document of each actor. 
Modify the following insertion query to add the following movies as an array: Life of Pie, Madagascar, and Hunger Games.

```
db.actor.insert({
 first: 'matthew',
 last: 'setter',
 dob: '21/04/1978',
 gender: 'm',
 hair_colour: 'brown',
 occupation: 'developer',
 nationality: 'australian',
 height_cm: 185
});
```

I thought it would be as easy as just adding this line into the code:

```
movies: ["Life of Pie", "Madagascar", "Hunger Games"]
```

but obviously, it's not that simple. I tried to find the syntax and examples for inserting an array, but had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `mongodb` documentation, you had the right idea:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

The example they give is:

```
var mydoc = {
           _id: ObjectId("5099803df3f4948bd2f98391"),
           name: { first: "Alan", last: "Turing" },
           birth: new Date('Jun 23, 1912'),
           death: new Date('Jun 07, 1954'),
           contribs: [ "Turing machine", "Turing test", "Turingery" ],
           views : NumberLong(1250000)
        }
```

So, it's possible you were just missing a comma after `height_cm: 185`:

```
db.actor.insert({
 first: 'matthew',
 last: 'setter',
 dob: '21/04/1978',
 gender: 'm',
 hair_colour: 'brown',
 occupation: 'developer',
 nationality: 'australian',
 height_cm: 185,
 movies: ["Life of Pie", "Madagascar", "Hunger Games"]
});
```